# Difference between if [ ... and test ... statement in bash

Tags: bash, test, exit-status

Consider the following:

```
echo "hello" > file.txt
is_match1 () {
  local m
  m=$(cat "file.txt" | grep -F "$1")
  if [ -z "$m" ]; then
    return 1
  fi
}
is_match2 () {
  local m
  m=$(cat "file.txt" | grep -F "$1")
  test -z "$m" && return 1
}
is_match1 "hello"
echo "$?"
0
is_match2 "hello"
echo "$?"
1
```

Why does `is_match2` return 1?

Comment: Related, take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/323060/what-is-the-general-consensus-on-useless-use-of-cat).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the circumstances of your question, `m` gets the value `hello` in both functions.

Now look at

```bsh
test -z "$m" && return 1
```

What should happen here?  The `-z` test is *false*, right? So `return 1` does not execute.  Instead, what does the function return?  Every function returns the value of `$?` at the end.  In this case, that value is 1, the result of the `&&` list.

What you might have wanted to test is

```bsh
if [ -z "$m" ]; then return 1; fi
```

compared to

```bsh
if test -z "$m"; then return 1; fi
```

The exit status of both these `if` statements are zero when `$m` is non-empty, since none of the statements' branches were taken.

From [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04):

> The exit status of the `if` command shall be the exit status of the `then` or `else` compound-list that was executed, or zero, if none was executed.

---

Note that we may condense both your functions down into

```
is_match () {
    grep -q -F -e "$1" file.txt
}
```

Here, we let `grep` provide the exit status to the caller.  We also do not necessarily read the `file.txt` file to the end, as `grep -q` quits as soon as it finds a match.

Comment: the exit status of an `if` statement is zero, _if_ none of the `then`/`else` branches were taken. `if false; then false; fi` leaves the exit status to 0, but `if true; then false; fi` leaves the exit status to 1. (even though in both cases the last command to run was `false`, and yes, I think it could return some other nonzero status too.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks. I was definitely not attempting to make generic statements about this. I have amended the text to use more careful language.

Comment: Also `is_match` should probably just be `is_match() { grep -qFe "$1" file.txt; }` or `is_match() { grep -qF -- "$1" file.txt; }`, unless you do *also* want to store the matching line in `$m` (but then that would be poorly chosen name for that global *reply* variable)

Comment: Or `is_match() { m=$(grep -F -- "$1" file.txt); }` if we do want to check if there was a match and store the matching lines (though not the empty trailing ones) in `$m`. `$m` could be empty despite a match if all the matching lines are empty or with some shells if the first matching line starts with a NUL byte.

Comment: I have edited the question to make `$m` a local variable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *For an empty pattern, this would return false (non-zero) if the file was empty. Testing with -z on the output from grep would in that case return true (zero).*. `printf '' | grep -qF ''` would return false and so would `[ -n "$(printf '' | grep -F '')" ]`. OTOH (and it's what I meant above), `printf '\n\n\n\n\n' | grep -qF ''` would return true, but `[ -n "$(printf '\n\n\n\n\n' | grep -F '')" ]` would return false as command substitution strips *all* trailing newline characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sorry, I totally messed that up. Too late in the day to be doing this. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @they, yeah. I think I just find the behaviour a bit odd, i.e. why would it not just leave the exit status of the last command in effect, regardless of if it was in a condition or in the inner branches. There's probably a sensible reason, but in a way it warrants a comment in my mind...